# Sitecore 9.0 installation Solr exception

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am installing sitecore 9.0 update 2 using SIF.
I am getting the follwoing error while accessing SOlr.

```
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\sitecoreinstall\xconnect-xp0.181016 (4).log
Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask : **error processing commands**
At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with using wrong solr version.I was using Solr version 7.5.
Sitecore version 9 is compatible only with the versions 6.6.1, 6.6.2, 6.6.3.I found the compatibility table at https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897.
I have uninstalled Solr 7.5 and installed 6.6.2 and no longer see the issue.